# npm audit fix --force gives the error code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE when trying to fix vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I was working with a react.js project and I installed **styled-components** using npm. When it installed, it gave:

```
74 vulnerabilities (14 low, 19 moderate, 37 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

I tried to run

```
npm audit fix --force
```

however it just repeats the process of listing the vulnerabilities and commands to fix it.

I tried to delete **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** and reinstall which I believe could be the cause. Didn't work and keeps giving the same results. Also, I looked up and it seems to be a problem between npm and react's frontend? Are these vulnerabilities dangerous or is it fine to continue?
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "first",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your `package.json`